# set uidatepicker date from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker

Question Updated:

I have an application where the user can add a new workshop including a workshop date that he chooses from a `UIDatePicker`. After that, the user can edit the workshop's information including changing the date. What I am trying to do is the following:
1. read the time the user choose from the `UIDatePicker` when he adds a new workshop.
2. convert the date to a string and save it in the database.
3. when the user wants to edit the workshop I should retrieve the workshop's date from the database and convert it from string to `NSDate`.
4. set the `UIDatePicker` in the Edit interface to the `NSDate` I just created.

I think this sound logical. however, it is not working for me and I am not sure why. here is the code:

in the `AddWorkshop.m` class

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
 //WSDate is a NSString variable
self.WSDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[sender date]];
```

in `EditWorkshop.m` class

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
 [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString: self.WSDate];
[self.datePicker setDate:date1];
```

the problem is:

1. the **`UIDatePicker` date would not change** to the specified date, it always shows today's date.
2. when I try to NSLog date1 and self.WSDate, the value of date1 is always **one day less** then the value of `self.WSDate`
3. is there a specific format for the date that I pass in [UIDatePicker setDate: NSDate] ? e.g: does it have to be "MMMM dd yyyy" or "mm-dd-yyyy" or any format is ok?

Comment: Can you share the code where you set `date1` in the `UIDatePicker`?

Comment: I updated the post.. the code is [self.datePicker setDate:date1];

Comment: why are you converting the date to string and why cant you store it as a timestamp just like core data

Comment: Regarding issue 1, it might be that case that you set the date in the wrong method or not on the UI thread. Regarding issue 2, why do you convert back and forth between `NSDate` and `NSString`? If possible you should store the `NSDate` itself. This is probably a timezone issue with your `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: because I am used to saving dates in strings in the database. never tried timestamp before. Even though, does this explain the UIDatePicker strange behavior ?

Comment: @Dennis ,I am setting the UIDatePicker date inside a method that is called in ViewDidLoad. I will try storing the NSDate itself though I never tried it before. However, will that explain the problem?

Comment: Storing it as `NSDate` will get you around the second problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a couple of weeks of trying I figured that the problem was I was allocating and initializing my `UIDatePicker` in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
```

therefore, when I use `[datePicker setDate: date];` it does not work. I don't know why exactly. but that was the case for me. I just deleted the `self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];` and the setDate method worked.

I will be happy if someone could explain more about why allocating the `UIDatePicker` made the `setDate` method not working. I thought that I need to allocate all new objects in order to use them because for example when I create a new `NSMutableArray` I cannot add objects to it if I don't allocate it first.
Thank you all for your efforts.

Comment: You don't need to allocate a property, when you use a property a memory A is assigned to it and when you reinitialize it a memory B is allocated to it, you will be in the mode that memory A will be used but its B which is actually being used hence deleting the re-allocation part did the trick for you, hope that explains

Comment: @NSDumb now I get it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1: `viewDidLoad` from where you want to update the `UIDatePicker` is called only once when your view is loaded. So this might be an issue in your case. Try calling the method from `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`

Ad 2: This is most probably a timezone issue. Try storing the date as `NSDate` instead of converting back and forth between `NSDate` and `NSString`.

Ad 3: `setDate:` expects an `NSDate`, which does not have a format. Think about it as something like an integer.

Comment: I did as you said in Ad 1 2, and the problem is still the same. The UIDatePicker would not set the NSDate I pass in [UIDatePicker setDate: date];

Comment: I NSLoged the date passed in the setDate: method and it was like this (2015-05-10 06:35:13 +0000) is that a correct date to pass to UIDatePicker?

Answer (score 0):

Never store `NSDate` as `NSString` in your database always try storing it as time stamp just like core data.

For your current issue given below is the code that should help you out, I am using an `IBAction` on `UIButton` which would display the converted `NSString` date in the `UIDatePicker` control.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

// set date of picker from string
NSDate *convertedDate = [self convertStringToDate];
if (convertedDate!=nil) {
    [self.datePicker setDate:convertedDate animated:YES];
}else{
    // Display any error here
}
  }

- (NSDate*)convertStringToDate{
    NSDateFormatter *SDF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [SDF setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSDate *convertedDate = [SDF dateFromString:[self convertTodaysDateintoString]];
    return convertedDate;
   }

- (NSString*)convertTodaysDateintoString{
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *str = [df stringFromDate:[self getTodaysDate]];
return str;
}

- (NSDate*)getTodaysDate{
return [NSDate date];
}
```

For issue number 2 please verify your time zone, I am not sure about question no 3 as of now I have not seen any specific date formats for `UIDatePicker` it just accepts a `NSDate`.

For 3 I would suggest to check the `UIDatePicker` mode also try setting the local to default in the XIB/storyboard attribute inspector.

[image: XIB attribute for UIDate Picker]

Comment: thank you for your effort. However, I spent the last few days trying your solution and it did not work for me. I also tried saving the date in database as time stamp using the sqlite3_bind_double(compileStatement1, 8, [date timeIntervalSince1970]);
and [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:dateFromDB]; I successfully stored and retrieved the date from the DB. However the problem with setting the UIDatePicker is still there :(

Comment: @Alsmayer: Did you check if you have attached the outlet correct to the UIDatePicker, i.e. if you are using .xib/.storyboard in your app

Comment: yes I have, several times. I even deleted the outlet and connected it again. I tried the same code in a clean new singleView project and it worked perfectly. Apparently, there is some conflict or something in my main project

Comment: @Alsmayer: If that's the case then i would suggest delete the class file in which you are adding the code for the picker and recreate it again and see if it works sometimes Xcode does behave strange

Comment: I did as you said but it did not work. However, your tip made me revise my code and realize that I was setting the UIDatePicker as new using `self.datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];` I deleted this code and everything worked out for me! `:)` I am going to post the answer and would be happy if you could explain why this is happening because it confuses me. Thank you for your efforts